# Visual Studio throwing a DirectX Shader Model 2.0 error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, hlsl

I'm very new to DirectX and am trying to run a shader that will update game objects from a passed in array. When I run the code I get the error "vs_2_0 does not support indexing". The issue that I am having though is that in my project properties I have the shader model set to Shader Model 4 Level 9_3 (/4_0_level_9_3). Here is my code so far:

GPURunner.cpp

```
int GPURunner::run() {
    // Define a struct for the game objects
    struct GameObject {
        float x, y, z;      // Position
        float r, g, b;      // Color
    };

    // Define a constant buffer to hold the array of game objects
    struct GameObjectBuffer {
        GameObject objects[100];
    };

    // Create the device and context
    ID3D11Device* device = nullptr;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* context = nullptr;
    HRESULT hr = D3D11CreateDevice(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &device, nullptr, &context);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the input buffer on the CPU
    GameObject gameObjects[100];

    // ... initialize the gameObjects array ...

    // Create the input buffer on the GPU
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC gameObjectBufferDesc = {};
    gameObjectBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(GameObject) * 100;
    gameObjectBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    gameObjectBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_UNORDERED_ACCESS;
    gameObjectBufferDesc.MiscFlags = D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_BUFFER_STRUCTURED;
    gameObjectBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(GameObject);

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA gameObjectData = {};
    gameObjectData.pSysMem = gameObjects;

    ID3D11Buffer* gameObjectBufferGPU = nullptr;
    hr = device->CreateBuffer(&gameObjectBufferDesc, &gameObjectData, &gameObjectBufferGPU);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the SRV for the buffer
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC gameObjectSRVDesc = {};
    gameObjectSRVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    gameObjectSRVDesc.Buffer.ElementWidth = 100;
    gameObjectSRVDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;

    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* gameObjectSRV = nullptr;
    hr = device->CreateShaderResourceView(gameObjectBufferGPU, &gameObjectSRVDesc, &gameObjectSRV);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    // Create the UAV for the buffer
    D3D11_UNORDERED_ACCESS_VIEW_DESC gameObjectUAVDesc = {};
    gameObjectUAVDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_UAV_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
    gameObjectUAVDesc.Buffer.NumElements = 100;
    gameObjectUAVDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;

    ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* gameObjectUAV = nullptr;
    hr = device->CreateUnorderedAccessView(gameObjectBufferGPU, &gameObjectUAVDesc, &gameObjectUAV);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    // Compile the compute shader from a file
    ID3DBlob* computeShaderBlob = nullptr;
    hr = D3DCompileFromFile(L"ComputeShader.hlsl", nullptr, nullptr, "CSMain", "cs_5_0", 0, 0, &computeShaderBlob, nullptr);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    ID3D11ComputeShader* computeShader = nullptr;
    hr = device->CreateComputeShader(computeShaderBlob->GetBufferPointer(), computeShaderBlob->GetBufferSize(), nullptr, &computeShader);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    // Set the compute shader
    context->CSSetShader(computeShader, nullptr, 0);

    // Set the SRV for the buffer
    context->CSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &gameObjectSRV);

    // Set the UAV for the buffer
    context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, &gameObjectUAV, nullptr);

    // Dispatch the compute shader
    context->Dispatch(100 / 64, 1, 1);

    // Unbind the SRV and UAV
    ID3D11ShaderResourceView* nullSRVs[] = { nullptr };
    ID3D11UnorderedAccessView* nullUAVs[] = { nullptr };
    context->CSSetShaderResources(0, 1, nullSRVs);
    context->CSSetUnorderedAccessViews(0, 1, nullUAVs, nullptr);

    // Copy the buffer from the GPU to the CPU
    GameObject gameObjectsOut[100];

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC gameObjectOutBufferDesc = {};
    gameObjectOutBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(GameObject) * 100;
    gameObjectOutBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;
    gameObjectOutBufferDesc.BindFlags = 0;
    gameObjectOutBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
    gameObjectOutBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
    gameObjectOutBufferDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(GameObject);

    ID3D11Buffer* gameObjectOutBufferGPU = nullptr;
    hr = device->CreateBuffer(&gameObjectOutBufferDesc, nullptr, &gameObjectOutBufferGPU);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    context->CopyResource(gameObjectOutBufferGPU, gameObjectBufferGPU);

    D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE mappedSubresource = {};
    hr = context->Map(gameObjectOutBufferGPU, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &mappedSubresource);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        // Handle the error
        return hr;
    }

    memcpy(gameObjectsOut, mappedSubresource.pData, sizeof(GameObject) * 100);

    context->Unmap(gameObjectOutBufferGPU, 0);

    // Cleanup
    computeShader->Release();
    computeShaderBlob->Release();
    gameObjectUAV->Release();
    gameObjectSRV->Release();
    gameObjectBufferGPU->Release();
    gameObjectOutBufferGPU->Release();
    context->Release();
    device->Release();
}
```

shader.hlsl

```
struct GameObject {
    float3 position;
    float3 velocity;
};

StructuredBuffer<GameObject> inputBuffer : register(t0);
RWStructuredBuffer<GameObject> outputBuffer : register(u0);

[numthreads(64, 1, 1)]
void main(uint3 dispatchThreadID : SV_DispatchThreadID) {
    uint index = dispatchThreadID.x;

    // Do some computation to update the GameObject at index
    outputBuffer[index].position += outputBuffer[index].velocity;
}
```

I've also gone into my computer specs and know that my graphics card is capable of running up to shader model 5.0

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is that shaders built for Direct3D Hardware Feature Level 9.1 or 9.3 have to meet the restrictions of the *older* shader model.

When you use the `4_0_level_9_3` profile, the same source is built TWICE: once with Shader Model 4.0, and then again with Shader Model 2.0 (2.x for `ps_4_0_level_9_3`, 2.0 for `ps_4_0_level_9_1`). If the HLSL language feature or shader complexity is not supported by Shader Model 2, then it won't build.

If you want to make use of Shader Model 4.0 only features, then you need to build using the `4_0` shader profile and require `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0` or better hardware to use it.

See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/direct3d-feature-levels/).